# Cross platform: require('..') and fs point to different location for globally installed node package

Tags: node.js, npm

A globally installed node package can overwrite its `config.json` with command line parameters.

The settings are read with `require('../config.json');` and are updated with:

```
var globalConfigPath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../config.json');
fs.writeFileSync(globalConfigPath, JSON.stringify(globalDefaults));
```

This works on my Windows machine both in local directory with `node index.js config ...` and as a globally installed package. In VirtualBox Debian however it only works in the local directory.

**When installed globally on Debian:**
With require, it appears to read from:
`/home/vagrant/.nave/installed/default/lib/node_modules/mymodule/config.json`

But the __dirname points to:
`/home/vagrant/.nave/installed/0.12.2/lib/node_modules/mymodule/config.json`

I worked around this by using fs for both the read and write but I'm still curious as to why they are not pointing to the same directory.

Comment: It's possible that `..../default` isn't really a directory but is merely a symlink to `..../0.12.2`. Can you `ls -l` that directory to check?

Comment: If they are symlinked shouldn't both be updated when I overwrite one of them?